# You dont have a write permission for gems on ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[[enter image description here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y02fm.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEv8x.png)

Hello

I am getting issue on ubuntu machine while installing **bundler**(screenshot attached) for ROR application my current ubuntu OS version is 22.04.

I tried to downgrade the bundler version but, it's not working.
Its showing I don't have write permission for gem folder.

Is that OS issue or if my make any mistake while installing.

Can you anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

can you please help whether this one ubuntu 22.04 OS issue or gems issue

Comment: please post text rather than screenshots

Comment: You really need to install a ruby version manger like RVM or RBenv so that you can have multiple versions of Ruby installed for different projects and not rely on the system Ruby. There will also install gems in a path which is writable. https://launchschool.com/books/core_ruby_tools/read/ruby_version_managers

Answer (score 0):

The error is because your project requires (either in the `Gemfile` or required by a different gem) a `google-api-client` version (the error says `google-api-client >= 0.9.5, < 0.33.0`) with a dependency on Ruby `2.x`. You're running Ruby 3 so bundler is complaining.

You either need to downgrade Ruby, or upgrade the gem (better). [In this commit](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/commit/a5faba567bb71a331531d2900210ee72cc9dc95b) on the `google-api-client` repo you can see the point where the gem was changed to allow Ruby 3+. From the list of tags listed at the top of the page, it looks like you need to make sure your project requires `google-api-client` v0.44.2 or greater.